# Controlling sizing in a form within a table

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, sizing

I have a table that has a form inside one of the cells. Because of the way that bootstrap controls input field sizing, it seems the documented way to do this is through this method

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes

But, because my form is sitting in a table, is there a way to do this properly?

Here is  what it looks like.. and it's def not right... I don't even think I can be putting rows inside my cell..

```
<td>    
<div class="row">
      <p>$00.00</p>
      <form role="form" class="form-inline cartAdd" name="itemAdd" method="post" action="shop.php">
         <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label class="sr-only" for="quantity">Quantity</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Qty" maxlength="3">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control pid" name="pid" class="pid" value="1" >
         </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="button" id="7PlateButton">Add</button>
        </div>

      </form>  
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: What is your end goal for formatting? Typically, you shouldn't be trying to use bootstrap rows/cols inside of a table element in general I wouldn't think. (since bootstrap already formats table elements).

I created a jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/Datadazer/4qbotyhk/